# Node.js How to store image as a blob after hosting in a VPS server

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

Please help me resolve my project issue. My nodejs project is hosted in hostinger VPs server using CentOS with cyberpanel

I have a feature of image upload which the process is from frontend(angular) to backend, the image is being uploaded to a temporary storage before storing to mysql database as a blob.

The issue is, when the multer is being executed, it sends an internal server error, which may be related to writing permission of the temp directory.

Is there any way to resolve the issue or upload the image without using a temporary storage?

first tried to use multer to upload the image before storing the path to database. when the error occured, I switched to upload the image in a /tmp storage before storing image as a blob

Comment: Ideally you don't store large assets in your database, but instead a reference to some object store like S3 or equivalent.

Comment: It's worth checking the upload limit set by your server's configuration. Some hosting providers have a default that's quite low. Also check your server's logs. Saying you're getting "an error" needs more technical detail.

Comment: I am a beginner in using VPS server. can you teach me how to check the upload limit of hostiger VPS server?

Comment: Is this a self-managed server or shared? Not familiar with that provider. Each stack has its own parameters, usually at the front-end server level (Apache `httpd`, Nginx or otherwise) as well as at the Node level. There is always some kind of limit to prevent someone from endlessly uploading a file and using up all your disk space.

Comment: as the customer support always say, it is an unmanaged server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.